# How to write overlapping lines when using 4 parts

Tags: notation

Here is an example of what I want to do. This is not a chorale hymn! But lets just use the naming conventions since I want 4 lines. The "Soprano" and "Alto" are providing an accompaniment for the tenor which is singing the melody and lyrics. They both momentarily drop below the tenor on the Dm chord at the end of the phrase. I have used a bass clef momentarily but not sure this is right. What is the best way to write something like this?

**I want to use these exact pitches and just need the best way to notate them.**

[image: Original score]

Comment: "Ranges are out but nevermind that": the question is about overlapping ranges.  You'll get more meaningful responses if you fix the range problems before asking the question.

Comment: There are some pretty strict rules when we're doing 4-part harmony. Writing for one voice with instrumental accompaniment lets you out of some of these rules. Maybe edit to make it more clear whether you're asking "are these good pitches to write," or "I want these pitches, what's the best way to notate them"? I agree you should not try to print the last half of m3 using treble clef; that's too many ledger lines. Also, I wouldn't describe these instrumental parts as "Soprano and Alto"; they're not in soprano and alto ranges, so it's just confusing.

Comment: Give yourself permission not to have four SATB parts. If this is, e.g., a rock song, and the top two "parts" are a single electric guitar, then they'll spend plenty of time overlapping with a tenor voice, or being even lower, and that's ok. If you're not writing a choral hymn, it might be time to explore the best way to notate for your intended ensemble.

Comment: Andy, I AM exploring! hence this post. Having 4 parts in this case has nothing to do with a chorale hymn. I just use 4 lines to get an idea and to limit myself. Anyway, I am all ears to see your idea. If they overlap, and they do, how do you notate this?

Comment: I changed the title. maybe that'll help to get some help. what I want is to add those two voices/lines to the bass and tenor and need to know how to write it. Cant be so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest way to understand the score overall would be to write it on three staves: top staff for the vocal part, plus a grand staff for the accompaniment.

[image: Three-staff revision of score]

In this specific case, though, given how low the treble staff part is, it would be most clear to write the entire part of the bass staff.

[image: Treble staff part moved to bass staff]

And, at least for this limited segment, the whole thing could be reduced to two staves.

[image: Two staff version: Tenor staff and accompaniment staff]

Comment: Absolutely! Though when composing personally I find it useful to use more staves rather than less, as handling multiple voices is a pain in most notation programs.

Comment: The problem for me personally is that I can read the counterpoint between the vocal and bass parts easier the other way when they are on the same staff. I guess with  more practice it wont matter. Why do you use a treble clef transposed an octave higher for the melody instead of a bass clef?

Comment: @armani The treble octave clef is typical for tenor vocal parts.

Answer (score 1):

F is a low note for alto, D is a very low note for alto. F is absolutely out of range for soprano.

Do you intend this to be sung by actual Singers or played on instruments of soprano/alto range? Most lines written for an instrument aligning to such a vocal range should be possible to notate without a clef change.

So if this is to be played on such an instrument or a singer you should not use a clef change but instead use a few ledger lines.

If this is to be played on an instrument of high range such as piano doing this clef change is fine.

Comment: No. The tenor is the singer and the bass is a bass guitar. I just wanted to get an idea of what other notes I could use in the voice leading. the guitar will likely play the other two notes but havent decided. If you think there is a better way to write this then I am keen to improve on it. thank you

Comment: @armani Hm, as the guitar is tenor instrument you’d notate it on octave higher anyway, so in this case everything can be treble clef. Nota bene: Guitar players are usually not used to clef changes!

Comment: but I need a solution that works in general. For example, I may not use guitar. Lets say I wanted to use non transposing instruments. How would you do it?

Comment: @armani There is no solution that works in general. Different instruments require different notation. A non transposing instrument of that range probably would be notated in bass clef. Of course you could just score the whole thing in a piano like manner and create a guitar score from that if needed. In a piano like manner having such a clef change is fine (although the whole part could be notated in bass clef).

Comment: so you mean with 2 bass clefs or just on one?

Comment: @armani Yes, I mean two bass clefs. Also may I inquire what the intended purpose of the score should be? Is a draft for you to compose the piece? Or is it something musicians should play from?

Comment: it is to be able to compose a song. The goal will be for recording the parts down in my studio. I like the idea if 2 bass clefs. And should I use a guitar then I will simply transpose up an octave. Thanks for helping

Comment: @armani If this notation is meant just to help you compose the song you can do anything you like, including clef changes. Only if you intend to create a score for publishing you should take such things into account.

Comment: @armani Sounds like this was a helpful answer. Please remember to upvote.